# get rows without duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a query I wrote a while ago that returns a count. I would now like to see the rows that are being counted but I can't seem to get my query right. Here is the query that returns the count.

```
    select count(distinct f_Shipmentnumber) from t_shipment shipment
    join t_Pilot pilot on pilot.f_PilotID=shipment.f_Pilot_ID
    where pilot.f_ProviderID='12' and shipment.f_ShipmentType=2 
    and shipment.f_date > DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
```

and here is what I have come up with, but it returns duplicate shipment numbers

```
    select * from t_shipment shipment
    join t_Pilot pilot on pilot.f_PilotID=shipment.f_Pilot_ID
    where pilot.f_ProviderID='12' and shipment.f_ShipmentType=2
    and shipment.f_date > DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
```

Any help would be great. Thank!!

Comment: Well what do you want to see when the same shipment has more than one pilot?

Comment: I just want to see the shipmentNumber once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer in comments, I assume when there is more than one pilot associated with a shipment, you don't care which pilot gets returned in the results.   In that case, you can solve this with a CTE and the Row_Number() function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f_Shipmentnumber ORDER BY f_Shipmentnumber) AS rn
    from t_shipment shipment
    join t_Pilot pilot on pilot.f_PilotID=shipment.f_Pilot_ID
    where pilot.f_ProviderID='12' and shipment.f_ShipmentType=2
    and shipment.f_date > DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: One more question. How can I return just the values from the shipment table? It is returning all values from both tables. I've tried using inner join but it's not working.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *`, you can do `SELECT shipment.*`  This is in the first SELECT, at the top of the query.  Not the one at the bottom.

Comment: Awesome that's perfect!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by, but in group by , you have to group by all columns and you have to decide which value you want to return on the other columns. some thing like this:

```
select f_Shipmentnumber,f_ProviderID,f_ShipmentType,Max(f_date )  from t_shipment shipment
join t_Pilot pilot on pilot.f_PilotID=shipment.f_Pilot_ID
where pilot.f_ProviderID='12' and shipment.f_ShipmentType=2
and shipment.f_date > DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
group by f_Shipmentnumber,f_ProviderID,f_ShipmentType
```

Comment: thanks Veen, That's not working. shipment number is used more than once. I want all the rows that meet the criteria but no duplicate shipmentNumber. Im getting this error now  Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a small mistake. Please try below